Function definition compiled inside .h file, but not on .cpp file, using C++17 and VS code
I was trying to implement in a .cpp file the definition of setColor(), which was correctly compiled before within the .h file from Sphere class, but now I get the next linker error:
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && g++.exe -std=c++17 -g -I include -L lib src\* -o bin\helloworld.exe -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglu32
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\sdelgado\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIOwL6S.o: in function `main':
C:\msys64\home\sdelgado\helloworld/src/main.cpp:55:(.text+0x1b3): undefined reference to `Sphere::setColor(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

sphere.h
class Sphere
{
public:
    float radio;
    float x;
    float y;
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    void setColor( unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
};

sphere.cpp
#include "sphere.h"
void Sphere::setColor(unsigned char r,unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
{
    red=r;
    green=g;
    blue=b;
}

main.cpp
#include "sphere.h"
Sphere sphere;
main()
{
[...]
sphere.setColor(200,0,0); 
}

Is it maybe necessary to add some other include that I am skipping?

Where is the sphere.cpp file located? Is it in the src directory? Are you certain you've saved it before you compiled? The filespec src\* should probably be src\*.cpp to avoid issues with any files that are not source code in that directory.

@RetiredNinja you were right, I didnt have those files in src, now it works

It was necessary to include every .h and .cpp files on the src folder.

yes, with your glob pattern not being recursive over directories. but if you'd used directory globbing, then you wouldn't need to. also, you are expected to have a [mre] in your question post. that includes task.json.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
